# Keycloak first login external provider

Tags: keycloak

I'm migrating my application's login to Keycloak, and I'm going to provide access via external providers (Google and Microsoft), but I'd like to configure an authentication flow for the following cases:

- If there is a user with the provider's email in the Keycloak base, the screen will be displayed for him to confirm the account binding.
- If the user does not exist, the form for updating the registration data previously filled in from the provider's data will be displayed to him.

I saw that they have 31 native Keycloak steps, but I couldn't find a combination that would handle this scenario, can anyone help me? I'm on Keycloak version 22.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily possible. Just take a look at the documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker_first_login

"Create User If Unique" and "Confirm Link Existing Account" are what you need.
The authentication flow should probably look similar to this:
[Authentication Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaxAG.png)